# WARNING: Error loading desktopfile

Tags: command-line, error-handling, gnome-tweak-tool, redshift

I have googled around and can't find any specific info on this. When I run gnome-tweaks, I get the error:

`WARNING : Error loading desktopfile: /home/sam/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop`

I don't use redshift-gtk as I preferred redshift w/o GTK. While this error is harmless, I wouldn't mind understanding why it happens and what can be done to fix it. I've tried `sudo apt autoremove/update/upgrade` to see if it was some old association of some sort, but it still persists.

E: Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .desktop file existed, it was probably installed along with package redshift-gtk.

Try `sudo apt-get remove --purge redshift-gtk`

You can check, gnome-tweaks has not any association with it:

```
apt-cache rdepends gtk-redshift
```

I'm guessing that if you remove the file, the error will go away:

```
rm /home/sam/.config/autostart/redshift-gtk.desktop
```